# Export EMl File without sending the Email Pod-Point / laravel-mail-export

Tags: laravel, email, eml

I am using this `Pod-Point/laravel-mail-export`   package to export eml files.But this package export the files of the sent emails I want to only export eml file and don't want to send the email. Is there any way to achive that.

Here is my Mailable

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use PodPoint\MailExport\Concerns\Exportable;
use PodPoint\MailExport\Contracts\ShouldExport;

class PlannerTemplateMailable extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue,ShouldExport 
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels,Exportable;


    public $message;
    public $files;
    public $customfrom;
    public $subject;
    public function __construct($message, $customfrom, $subject, $files = [])
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->files = $files;
        $this->customfrom = $customfrom;
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }

    public function build()
    {

        $email = $this->from($this->customfrom)
            ->subject($this->subject)
            ->markdown('mails.planner-template')
            ->with([
                'message' => $this->message,
            ]);

        foreach ($this->files as $file) {
            $email->attach($file);
        }

        return $email;
    }
}
```